# VLOOKUP in 2 sheets of an excel

Tags: excel

I have a column in Sheet 1 of an excel which I want to compare with an column of Sheet 2 of the same excel.
The values of Sheet 1 column to be present in some rows of Sheet 2 column (not necessary to be row by row).

How to use VLOOKUP here ?

Comment: Consider using **MATCH()**

Comment: Thanks. Could you please show me an example?
If both columns are in same sheet, I use a formula like this: NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$B:$B,1,FALSE)))

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!B:B,0)),"no match","match")
```